# Create function to display ACF field on single product page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to display additional text on the single product page in a Woocommerce theme. Right now I'm stuk at the part where I have to create the function. I get the basics of get_field() but I'm unsure how to get the post ID in there... or if that's even all I need... Here's what I got so far for this part:

```
$product_id = wp_get_post_terms($post_id);
$text = get_field('product_text', $product_id);
```

I've tried a couple of different ones but I can't seem to get it to work. I did the exact same thing for the category pages:

```
$category_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
$textfield = get_field('product_cat_description', 'category_' . $category_id);
```

I'd say all I need is the post ID like I did with get_queried_object() for the category pages but I'm not sure how to get this for products.

Answer (score 0):

The following did it:

$seo_text = get_field('product_seo_text', $product->ID);

I also added a conditional checking if the field had content but I don't think that has anything to do with the fix.

Comment: You should use `$product->get_id()`

Comment: Using $product->get_id() instead of $product->ID messes up the page. What's wrong with $product->ID?

Comment: `$product->ID` will produce a tonne of warnings in your PHP logs. `$product->get_id()` uses the CRUD methods and is the official way to get a product ID. It also ensure you get the right ID and applies any filters.

You could try:

`global $product;`
`$product_id = $product->get_id();`
`$seo_text = get_field( 'product_seo_text', $product_id );`

However, if you're already on the single product page you shouldn't even need to pass an ID:

`$seo_text = get_field( 'product_seo_text' );`

That should work too.

Comment: Ohh got it! Thanks for clearing that up. I'll see if that works then.